Is there a more obscure word that means "smallest"?
I was writing recently and wanted to use a word like "smallest", but with more of a dramatic flair. I'd also accept words in the same vein as "weakest", "youngest", etc.—any sort of diminutive superlatives/comparison.
For context, this is the phrase:

The smallest flicking tail of the continent.

("Flicking tail" means peninsula here, as i said the piece is very figurative. I know peninsulas don't "flick", that would be weird, it's a case of personification.)
I'm trying to convey that the continent has multiple peninsulas, and this is the smallest. Thesauruses don't work here because they (reasonably) redirect comparative words to the base adjective, but I'm specifically looking for a superlative here, or at least a word that indicates comparison. Something like "runt", but as an adjective?
I'd accept a multi-word answer here, but I'm hoping there's an option that's only one. More figurative words would also work (hence the "runt" example.) I figure there's a chance this word doesn't exist, but it's worth a shot.

Have you checked in a thesaurus for 'smallest' and 'small'? One quickly arrives at 'most miniscule' // 'most unimportant / trifling / trivial / insignificant / inconsequential / inappreciable' (not all of which fit the example sentence ... but some of which do).

@EdwinAshworth My bad for not clarifying very well in the original post, but  I'm using "smallest" comparatively to indicate there are others and they are all larger. Thesauruses generally have just turned up "very small" or "least in size possible".

I still don't understand. You don't like any of Edwin Ashworth's suggestions? Are you saying you don't want a superlative form of a word that means small? (Tiniest, teensiest, minutest, littlest, wee-est, squattest, puniest, etc) Or you do want a superlative? Or some other category of word that has some other meaning? Or is the problem that you're looking for a word with a particular sound or connotation?

@StuartF I'm looking for a word to refer to the smallest/weakest/etc of a group of objects, specifically a more obscure or odd word for it for tone reasons. superlatives are definitely my primary interest, but i realize now its probably not the limit. Something in the same ballpark as "runt", although as an adjective?

What’s weird is multiple tails—flicking or not.

The continent has more than one flicking tail?? Anyway, the continent as horse or donkey?

Perhaps

A cilium upon the back end of the continent.

That's it - don't use an adjective, use a noun. You might not like cilium, so think of another tiny wee appendage and use that instead. I think this is way more dramatic than any of the adjectival expressions you've already had suggested.
To back up this suggestion - any number of writing guides which propose the avoidance of adverbs and adjectives in favour of nouns and verbs.

The singular of cilia is cilium.

I don't see this at all.

Insignificant carries the meaning

insignificant [adjective]

too small or unimportant to be worth consideration. [Oxford Dictionary of English; courtesy
Google]


It does, however, require the periphrastic superlative most insignificant (or perhaps better stylistically, the equivalent least significant).
Related in meaning is 'negligible', but this doesn't grade too well, being an extreme adjective.

I think "least significant" or maybe "least prominent" would work here, although they don't preserve the exact poetic tone I'm going for they fit alright for now. Thanks for the suggestion though, it's provided a good jumping point.

Or simply least.
